# INSERT failing on SELECT * but runs fine when columns are mentioned explicitly

Tags: sql, insert, teradata

I have two identical tables with 1x1 view on them. Both have same columns and datatypes in same order.

When I execute the below command,

```
INSERT INTO MAIN_DB.TABLE_A 
   SELECT * FROM TEMP_DB.TABLE_A;
```

it fails and pops the below error

> ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database]
>   Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval. INSERT Command Failed.

However when I run INSERT query with **explicit column names** instead of *
. It executes just fine.

This works just fine -

```
INSERT INTO MAIN_DB.TABLE_A 
   SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3..... COL85 FROM TEMP_DB.TABLE_A;
```

I am unable to pin point -

- Why is this happening ?
- How to find which column is getting invalid
  date ?

EDIT - The table columns are in exact same order (and same datatype).

> SHOW TABLE MAIN_DB.TABLE_A

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE MAIN_DB.TABLE_A ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      COL1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      COL2 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      COL3 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL4 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL5 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL6 INTEGER,
      COL7 CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL8 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL9 VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL10 VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL11 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL12 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL13 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL14 TIMESTAMP(6),
      COL15 TIMESTAMP(6),
      COL16 TIMESTAMP(6),
      COL17 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd' COMPRESS ,
      COL18 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL19 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL20 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL21 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL22 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL23 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL24 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL25 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL26 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL27 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL28 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL29 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL30 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL31 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL32 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL33 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL34 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL35 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL36 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL37 TIMESTAMP(6),
      COL38 SMALLINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ),
      COL39 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL40 TIMESTAMP(6),
      COL41 VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL42 DECIMAL(18,0) COMPRESS 0. ,
      COL43 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL44 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL45 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL46 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL47 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL48 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL49 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
      COL50 CHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC COMPRESS,
      COL51 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL52 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL53 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL54 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL55 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL56 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL57 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL58 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL59 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL60 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL61 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL62 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL63 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL64 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL65 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL66 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL67 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL68 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL69 TIMESTAMP(6),
      COL70 CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL71 DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
      COL72 INTEGER COMPRESS (60 ,61 ,62 ),
      COL73 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
      COL74 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
      COL75 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL76 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
      COL77 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL78 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL79 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL80 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL81 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL82 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL83 VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL84 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      COL85 VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX NUPI_TABLE_A  ( COL1 )
PARTITION BY RANGE_N(COL2  BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2025-01-29' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY ,
 NO RANGE OR UNKNOWN);
```

> SHOW TABLE TEMP_DB.TABLE_A

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TEMP_DB.TABLE_A ,FALLBACK ,
         NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
         NO AFTER JOURNAL,
         CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
         DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
         (
          COL1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
          COL2 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          COL3 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL4 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL5 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL6 INTEGER,
          COL7 CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL8 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL9 VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL10 VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL11 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL12 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL13 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL14 TIMESTAMP(6),
          COL15 TIMESTAMP(6),
          COL16 TIMESTAMP(6),
          COL17 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd' COMPRESS ,
          COL18 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL19 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL20 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL21 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL22 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL23 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL24 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL25 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL26 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL27 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL28 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL29 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL30 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL31 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL32 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL33 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL34 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL35 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL36 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL37 TIMESTAMP(6),
          COL38 SMALLINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ),
          COL39 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL40 TIMESTAMP(6),
          COL41 VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL42 DECIMAL(18,0) COMPRESS 0. ,
          COL43 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL44 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL45 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL46 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL47 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL48 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL49 INTEGER COMPRESS 0 ,
          COL50 CHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC COMPRESS,
          COL51 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL52 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL53 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL54 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL55 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL56 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL57 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL58 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL59 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL60 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL61 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL62 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL63 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL64 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL65 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL66 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL67 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL68 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL69 TIMESTAMP(6),
          COL70 CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL71 DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
          COL72 INTEGER COMPRESS (60 ,61 ,62 ),
          COL73 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
          COL74 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
          COL75 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL76 BYTEINT COMPRESS (0 ,1 ),
          COL77 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL78 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL79 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL80 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL81 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL82 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL83 VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL84 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          COL85 VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
    PRIMARY INDEX NUPI_TABLE_A  ( COL1 )
    PARTITION BY RANGE_N(COL2  BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2020-01-30' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY ,
     NO RANGE OR UNKNOWN);
```

Actual column names are changed to COL1, COL2 ... so on.

Comment: Add `show table ...` for both tables to your post

Comment: How many columns are there in MAIN_DB.TABLE_A?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Added show table for both.

Comment: @access_granted 85 columns in both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the issue.

The table was altered and reverted back. However the view didn't refresh on with this.

For e.g.

Initially table was

```
COL1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
COL2 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
COL3 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
```

then it was changed to

```
COL1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
COL2 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
COL3 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
NEW_COLUMN VARCHAR(100)
```

and reverted back to

```
COL1 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
COL2 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
COL3 VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
```

However the view was never refreshed after reverting back.

```
REPLACE VIEW MAIN_DB.TABLE_A AS LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS SELECT * FROM MAIN_DB_T.TABLE_A;
```

So even though everything was how it should be. The view was creating all the fuss. I refreshed the view and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can guess what the problem is.  The columns in `MAIN_DB.TABLE_A` are not in the same order as the columns in `TEMP_DB.TABLE_A`. When you use `*` they do not line up.  Remember, the `INSERT` goes by column position, not by column name.

When using `INSERT`, you should always list out the columns both for the `INSERT` and for the values going in:

```
INSERT INTO MAIN_DB.TABLE_A (COL1, COL2 . . . )
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3..... COL85
    FROM TEMP_DB.TABLE_A;
```

You may complain that the query is longer and more complicated, but it is really pretty easy to get the list of columns from both tables.  Then the code is much more robust.

Comment: The columns are in the same order. I compared table definitions in **Beyond Compare**

Comment: Differing data types?  `SELECT *` is evil for anything beyond a one-off.

Comment: @PirateX Gordon's diagnosis of what the problem is may not be correct.  However, his solution is 100% correct: "When using INSERT, you should always list out the columns both for the INSERT and for the values going in".  Using Select * for this is just a really bad coding practice because there are lots of ways it can break

Comment: @Andrew Data types aren't differing. The data types in the tables are exactly the same. See the show table command.

Comment: @DavidCram The solution provided by him is correct when columns are not in same order. Mine's not the case.